# Go from Activity to Fragment on NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I've got an Activity that acts like a presentation, I want to put some buttons so I can go directly to particular fragment (the one I choose from the MainActivity).

I've tried with getSupportFragment and Activity.getSupportFragment but nothing works. And, obviously, neither with a simple intent.

Thanks.

This is the MainActivity "Splash":

```
  public class Splash extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_splash);


    }
}
```

The start of the FragmentActivity. It's not complete, so it contain errors. This is the Activity that contains the Fragments

```
public class FragmentActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();
```

To switch between Views, I use:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment views=null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //news
            views= new news();
            break;
        case 1:
            //time
            views=new time();
            break;
        case 2:
            //Ins
            views=new Ins() ;
            break;

    }

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, views)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Please attach some existing code

Comment: I don't get it: what you need? where are Fragments? please put a screen or some code :)

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Np, i have one more question: if i get it you have a page with 3(or more) fragments in it, and based on which button is clicked you wanna make a particular fragment visible and others hidden right?

Comment: Yes, I have and Activity that I want to acts like a "pre-menu". In it (The Splash Activity) I want to put some buttons refering to each fragment. So, if i press the button called "Time", I show the Fragment activity showing the time view.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i can try giving you a solution: instead of creating a new view, you can add all fragments to the SplashActivity following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ6uc__qP-g) guide.

Than set all fragment to be with `View.GONE`.
Once an user click a button, change the View property of the related fragment to `Visible` and all others to `Gone`.

Doing this everytimes an user clicks a button, all Fragments disappears except the one you need.

This should work but i suggest to have a look to [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8hSIP2ha-g) guide on how to use NavigationDrawer propertly.

Hope i helped, good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with the guide and the documentation

Comment: no problem, that was the first guide i found but the web is full, chose the one you prefer! :)